# How to classify land cover with MMU 25hac

Tags: spatial-analyst, remote-sensing, land-classification, landsat-5, minimum-mapping-unit

By using the 30 meter resolution of landsat TM & ETM+ data, I want to create the land use/ land cover map. I have read in several studies to first decide about the minimum mapping unit (MMU) that is manifested by CORINE land use land cover for Landsat data. How can I specifically make analysis by using 25hac (90x90).

Comment: I'd suggest to firstly perform a classification that respects the image's native spatial resolution (30 by 30).  Or even, if you pan-sharpen, and get good results, use the Panchromatic's higher resolution.  Then, depending on your workflow, you can generalize.